Getting Error when starting Code ready start "ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:41804->127.0.0.1:2222: read: connection reset by peer" i
Host OS
NAME="Fedora Linux"
VERSION="40 (Server Edition)"
** crc version**
CRC version: 2.43.0+268795
OpenShift version: 4.17.1
MicroShift version: 4.17.1
virsh --version
Virsh command line tool of libvirt 10.1.0
See web site at https://libvirt.org/
Compiled with support for:
Hypervisors: QEMU/KVM LXC LibXL OpenVZ VMware VirtualBox ESX Hyper-V Test
Networking: Remote Network Bridging Interface udev Nwfilter
Storage: Dir Disk Filesystem SCSI Multipath iSCSI iSCSI-direct LVM RBD Gluster ZFS
Miscellaneous: Daemon Nodedev SELinux Secrets Debug DTrace Readline
crc start debug output
INFO CRC instance is running with IP 127.0.0.1
DEBU Waiting until ssh is available               
DEBU retry loop: attempt 0                        
DEBU Running SSH command: exit 0                  
DEBU Using ssh private keys: [/home/crc/.crc/machines/crc/id_ed25519 /home/crc/.crc/cache/crc_libvirt_4.17.1_amd64/id_ecdsa_crc] 
DEBU SSH command results: err: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:38792->127.0.0.1:2222: read: connection reset by peer, output:  
DEBU error: Temporary error: ssh command error:
command : exit 0
err     : ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:38792->127.0.0.1:2222: read: connection reset by peer
 - sleeping 1s 
DEBU retry loop: attempt 1                        
DEBU Running SSH command: exit 0

Error when trying to access using
virsh console
virsh console crc
Connected to domain 'crc'
Escape character is ^] (Ctrl + ])
error: internal error: character device serial0 is not using a PT
CRC CONSOLE login details
virsh console crc
Connected to domain 'crc'
Escape character is ^] (Ctrl + ])
error: internal error: character device serial0 is not using a PTY

virsh console crc
Connected to domain 'crc'
Escape character is ^] (Ctrl + ])
error: internal error: character device serial0 is not using a PTY
